# Error: "message": "Login Required" when use Youtube Analytics API

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api

I am working with youtube api. when I hit this url "**https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3DMINE&start-date=2015-01-01&end-date=2016-01-31&metrics=likes%2Cdislikes&key={API Key}**"

it gives 401

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

but I hited in the explorer "https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?"
it working fine.
How do I make the first request work?

Comment: you should fix your question this is a request to the YouTube  analytics api.   You need to be authenticated for that request use Oauth2.

Comment: I already have the access token from Oauth from a different mean. Now how do I get this data?

Comment: try https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3DMINE&start-date=2015-01-01&end-date=2016-01-31&metrics=likes%2Cdislikes&access_token={access token from oauth}

Comment: key= is for a public api key.   Access_token= is when you have an oauth2 access token.

Comment: thanks @Dalm. Its working

Comment: Yeah the docs should change the generated URL from key={API key} to access_token={access token} when using Oauth would make it all a lot easier to read and understand

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In your request you are sending key={your key} for an access token you should be sending access_token={your oauth2 access token}

Note: Key is used for public requests.  access token is for authenticated requests.

Comment: Is there a way to just use my key without an Oauth token?  I know it's not secure, but this is just a proof of concept I'm trying to draw up real quick.  And will probably replace with Oauth later

Answer (score 6):

If someone else using JWT authentication on a Google API stumbles upon this question (eg. when using Service Accounts) then make sure to include `auth: <your jwtClient>` in your API call, like:

**First, get the token:**

```
// Configure JWT auth client
var privatekey = require("./<secret>.json")
var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
  privatekey.client_email,
  null,
  privatekey.private_key,
  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
);

// Authenticate request
jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
  if (err) {
    return;
  } else {
    console.log("Google autorization complete");
  }
});
```

Then, call the API **(but don't forget the `auth:jwtClient` part)**

```
drive.files.create({
    auth: jwtClient,
    resource: {<fileMetadata>},
    fields: 'id'
  }, function (err, file) {
    if (err) {
      // Handle error
    } else {
      // Success is much harder to handle
    }
});
```