# How to use api key to access the Google Drive

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, api-key

I am trying to use  apiGoogle Node.js client library to access the Google Drive API so I can upload some files to my drive account.

My code so far:

```
var drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3' });
drive.apiKey = "API_KEY"
drive.setScope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"

drive.files.create({
    resource: {
        name: 'text.text',
        mimeType: 'text/plain',
        parents:['1ATscm2nsE9KpjA66iXHB9jnMrbyik7PP']
    },
    media: {
        mimeType: 'text/plain',

        body: fs.createReadStream('files/text.text')

    }
});
```

Errors:

```
 errors: 
   [ { domain: 'global',
       reason: 'required',
       message: 'Login Required',
       locationType: 'header',
       location: 'Authorization' } ] }
```

Can anybody help to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34894091/error-message-login-required-when-use-youtube-analytics-api). Make sure that you are sending `access_token={your oauth2 access token}` and not `key={your key}` for an access token. You may check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes) for more information.